# How to adapt this code to insert saveas dialog box

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below to save one worksheet of my workbook, I would like to change some things, one of the things I am trying to change and I am having some issues with this is to add a SaveAsBox in my code. Nowadays when I run the macro automatically save the new worksheet in a specif folder, I do not want to save this way anymore, I would like to run the macro and pops-up the SaveAs box with the suggest name "Savings" and the File Type "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook"
Could you guys help me figure this out?

```
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\luuke\Desktop"
    path = FolderPath & "\*.xlsx"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

   Sheets("Savings").Select
   Sheets("Savings").Copy
    ChDir _
         FolderPath
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        FolderPath & "\Relatorio_Saving " & count & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to have a Save dialog box so that you can input the desired filename instead of hard coding it ?

Comment: @gr8tech Exactly, I just like to Suggest a name (On the name Field show Savings), but not to save as a code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
Dim name as Variant 

name=Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Relatorio_Saving " & count 
                                     & ".xlsx","Excel File 
                                   (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If name <> "" then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs name,xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
```

Comment: Compile Error: Expected: list separator or) 

Appears this error and the line name = ... be red